# Polylang + ACF - Fields Group on front page is not displaying on translated pages

Tags: wordpress

I've just installed **Polylang** (Free version) and I have field group that is set to be displayed on **front-page**.

In the admin, fields are displaying correctly on the main language's front page but not on the translated front-page.

I've searched to see what could go wrong and it's obviously because of **ACF** that is only checking if we are on the front page with `get_option('page_on_front')`.

And polylang doesn't seems to filter the value to set the right front-page.

So I found this **mu-plugin**:

```
<?php

class ACF_Page_Type_Polylang {

  // Whether we hooked page_on_front
  private $filtered = false;

  public function __construct() {

      add_filter( 'acf/location/rule_match/page_type', array( $this, 'hook_page_on_front' ) );
  }

  public function hook_page_on_front( $match ) {

      if ( ! $this->filtered ) {
          add_filter( 'option_page_on_front', array( $this, 'translate_page_on_front' ) );
          // Prevent second hooking
          $this->filtered = true;
      }

      return $match;
  }

  public function translate_page_on_front( $value ) {

      if ( function_exists( 'pll_get_post' ) ) {
          $value = pll_get_post( $value );
      }

      return $value;
  }
}

new ACF_Page_Type_Polylang();
```

but it does not resolve the issue and i don't know why, the code seems correct.

If I only take this part :

```
add_filter( 'option_page_on_front', array( $this, 'translate_page_on_front' ) );
```

and convert it to :

```
add_filter( 'option_page_on_front',function() { return '346' });
```

(*346 is the translated front-page ID)*

it filters properly the option page_on_front and my fields are displaying correctly.

Can you help me make the mu-plugin works ?

Answer (score 4):

I've found a way to make it work but I don't know if it's the right way ... can you please tell me ?

```
<?php

class ACF_Page_Type_Polylang {

  // Whether we hooked page_on_front
  private $filtered = false;

  public function __construct() {

      add_filter( 'acf/location/rule_match/page_type', array( $this, 'hook_page_on_front' ) );
  }

  public function hook_page_on_front( $match ) {

      // Abort if polylang not activated
      if ( !function_exists( 'pll_get_post' ) ) {
         return $match;
      }

      // Get the main language front page 
      $front_page = (int) get_option('page_on_front');

      // Get the translated page of the curent language
      $translated_page = pll_get_post($front_page);

      // Check if it's the same as the current page and set match to true if so
      if($translated_page === get_the_id()) {
        $match = true;
      }

      return $match;
  }
}

new ACF_Page_Type_Polylang();
```

Comment: I put your code in a plugin file, activated it, and it works like charm! I've no idea if it's "the right way" but it does work, so kudos!

Comment: A three years old answer that still works, awesome ^^